# Store user passwords in plain text in OpenLDAP server

Tags: docker, ldap, openldap

I am using OpenLDAP provided in `osixia/openldap` docker image (https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) but it is storing all passwords hashed.

Normally it will be desirable but I am planning to hash passwords on front end (with salting and MD5) so no person in the organization never gets to see the users passwords,  but when I try saving them they are hash again, I have not find a way to prevent this behavior.

I try deleting (using user `cn=admin,cn=config`) an entry that comes with the image called `cn={4}ppolicy,cn=schema,cn=config` which I think may be the culprit but `ldapdelete` returns `Server is unwilling to perform (53)`.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Error 53 means you don't have enough privilege to perform the operation. But your question doesn't make sense.If you store passwords in plain-text, your LDAP admins can see them, which is not what you want. See [tag:password-encryption] for why not.You should ensure LDAPS is used for all access, then nobody in the organization can ever see the passwords.

Comment: And deleting the schemas that come with `ppolicy` doesn't make any more sense than the rest of your question.

Comment: Again, I am already hashing user passwords on the front end, so having ldap also do it is causing the password to be stored double hashed, I am not an expert cryptographer by any means of the imagination, but is it not a bad thing to hash passwords twice?

Answer (score -1):

If you store the password in plain text you can retrieve them in plain text.

You just need to check in the ACL that the user you use to read them have the correct rights to do it.

The password policy entry you are talking about is just a schema definition which allows you to define a password policy but does not enforce anything. (The 53 error is because you can't remove a schema from a running OpenLDAP to prevent removing a schema which could be used by an entry)

According to what I can see in github about the docker image you use, the ACL used is :

```
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange 
           by self write 
           by dn="cn=admin,{{ LDAP_BASE_DN }}" write 
           by anonymous auth 
           by * none
```

Which means that only the user himself or the admin account can read the password field `userPassword`

It is this ACL that you need to modify to suit your needs. The ACL should be located here :

`dn: olcDatabase={1}{{ LDAP_BACKEND }},cn=config`

Comment: It does enforce things. Lots of them. Password length, quality, expiration, failed logins, grace logins,reuse, ...

Comment: @user207421 No, adding a schema does not enforce anything, please re-read what I wrote.

Comment: It most certainly does. Provided your configuration and code is correct. Clearly yours is not. Otherwise the overlay would be pointless.

Comment: @user207421 Where was the overlay configured? He tried to remove a schema definition to resolve his problem which will not resolve anything, I pointed that out, end of it

Comment: It was configured with `cn={4}ppolicy,cn=schema,cn=config`. And changing permissions as per your answer has no effect on how passwords are stored. Not that the password policy does either.

Comment: @user207421 This is a schema defintion, not the configuration of the overlay ... hence why it is in the ```cn=schema``` branch, please, read the doc : http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html

Comment: This schema definition provides the schemas necessary for the operation of the `ppolicy`. Deleting it makes exactly no sense, and providing the user with permission to modify `userPassword` doesn't change how the password is stored, or solve the orignal 53 problem either.

Comment: @user207421 The 53 error is because he tried to remove a schema while the directory is running ... that is not part of his question ...

Comment: Sorry for having you discussing this, I am quite new with ldap, I just read that ppolicy is the way password hashing is configure so I thought of deleting it, I just what to store password in plain text (I am hashing and salting them outside of the ldap, I want to prevent double hashing)